# Hadoop DistCp using wildcards?

Tags: hadoop

Is it possible to use DistCp to copy only files that match a certain pattern? 
For example. For /foo I only want *.log files.

Answer (score 19):

I realize this is an old thread. But I was interested in the answer to this question myself - and dk89 also asked again in 2013.  So here we go:

distcp does not support wildcards. The closest you can do is to:

Find the files you want to copy (sources), filter then using grep, format for hdfs using awk, and output the result to  an  "input-files" list:

```
hadoop dfs -lsr hdfs://localhost:9000/path/to/source/dir/ 
  | grep -e webapp.log.3. | awk '{print "hdfs\://localhost\:9000/" $8'}   > input-files.txt
```

Put the input-files list into hdfs

```
hadoop dfs -put input-files.txt  .
```

Create the target dir

```
hadoop dfs -mkdir hdfs://localhost:9000/path/to/target/
```

Run distcp using the input-files list and specifying the target hdfs dir:

```
hadoop distcp -i -f input-files.txt hdfs://localhost:9000/path/to/target/
```

Answer (score 2):

DistCp is in fact just a regular map-reduce job: you can use the same globbing syntax as you would use for input of a regular map-reduce job. Generally, you can just use `foo/*.log` and that should suffice. You can experiment with `hadoop fs -ls` statement here - if globbing works with `fs -ls`, then if will work with DistCp (well, almost, but differences are fairly subtle to mention).

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working with s3n:// paths. Hadoop -ls works with s3n:// wildcards, though.. weird.

Comment: This question is from 2011, was there a change made to enable distcp with wildcards?

Comment: Version 2 supports wildcards, doc here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/distcp2.html